# Conversion of SRAM MTH 746 from Shimano to SRAM XD Freehub

Tags: mountain-bike, sram, upgrades, freehub

I own Santa Cruz Tallboy AL R-kit which comes with SRAM PG1230, 12spd, 11-50t Cassette (NX level).
I want to upgrade to GX-level drivetrain. The GX goupset comes with XG-1275 Eagle cassette with 10-52 teeth.
My current rear hub is SRAM MTH 746, 12x148, 32h mounted on RaceFace AR rims.

My understanding is the rear-hub will have to be converted from Shimano HG to SRAM XD Freehub. Is it possible to swap only the Driver Body and what is the part /part number I need to buy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, possible.

The part number is elusive but a simple search on “SRAM MTH 746 xd freehub” provides many online stores who sell the part.